# PrimeFaces: AccordionPanel: error message of required input

Tags: primefaces

I have an AccordionPanel with three tabs. In the first tab is a form with required inputTexts.  Now I have a problem, the error message diplays in all three tabs, not only in one. Any advices? How can I set an error message of required input only for one tab?

```
<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true">
    <p:tab title="Change your details" id="tabDetails">
    <p:messages id="message1" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" id="gridDetails">
            <h:outputText value="First name: *" /> 
            <p:inputText value="#{login.current.firstName}" id="firstName" required="true" />
            <!-- ... -->
                        <p:commandButton value="save" actionListener="#{login.saveModifications}" update="gridDetails"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab> 
    <p:tab title="Change your password" id="tabPass">
    <p:messages id="message2" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="10" id="gridPass">                    
            <!-- ... -->            
            <p:commandButton value="save" actionListener="#{login.changePassword}" update="gridPass" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
        <!-- ... -->
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `p:messages` show every JSF messages from the view. If you want to show only specific ones, you need to use the attribute `for`.

In your case, that should do the trick :

```
<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true">
    <p:tab title="Change your details" id="tabDetails">
    <p:messages id="message1" for="btn1" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" id="gridDetails">
            <h:outputText value="First name: *" /> 
            <p:inputText value="#{login.current.firstName}" id="firstName" required="true" />
            <!-- ... -->
                        <p:commandButton id="btn1" value="save" actionListener="#{login.saveModifications}" update="gridDetails"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab> 
    <p:tab title="Change your password" id="tabPass">
    <p:messages id="message2" for="btn2" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="10" id="gridPass">                    
            <!-- ... -->            
            <p:commandButton id="btn2" value="save" actionListener="#{login.changePassword}" update="gridPass" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
        <!-- ... -->
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Note : I've added specific ID to your action components (`p:commandButton`).

**More info :**

- [p:messages](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/messages.html)
- [FacesMessages enhancement](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1894)